# HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() clarification

Tags: c#, .net-core

It is not clear enough from the documentation whether `HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` takes the content already existing in memory and copies the content to a new `byte[]` which it then returns to the consumer, or whether the `byte[]` it returns is effectively pointing to the same location that the already existing content in memory is at.

In other words, can someone clarify whether there's new memory allocated for the returned `byte[]` or not?

I'm specifically asking about .NET 5 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decompile the `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` method you get this:

```
private MemoryStream bufferedContent;

[global::__DynamicallyInvokable]
public Task<byte[]> ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
{
    CheckDisposed();
    TaskCompletionSource<byte[]> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
    LoadIntoBufferAsync().ContinueWithStandard(delegate(Task task)
    {
        if (!HttpUtilities.HandleFaultsAndCancelation(task, tcs))
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(bufferedContent.ToArray());
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}

[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public virtual byte[] ToArray()
{
    byte[] array = new byte[_length - _origin];
    Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(_buffer, _origin, array, 0, _length - _origin);
    return array;
}
```

The `.ToArray()` call clearly allocates new memory.